# Problem with MatIcon centering in MatButtonToggle on Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, angular-material

I'm trying to adjust the MatButtonToggle, but I'm having problems with centering the MatIcon, I've tried a dozen or so ways to adjust it, but to no avail, a seemingly mundane matter, and yet the trouble is enough - so bad.
I kindly please show me how to adjust it.
Thank you in advance.

[image: problem with center MatIcon in angular material MatButtonToggle]

The template:

```html
<mat-toolbar class="mainToolbar">
  <mat-button-toggle-group #modeAppWorking="matButtonToggleGroup">
    <mat-button-toggle value="setup" class="mainTollbar-button">
      <mat-icon>settings_applications</mat-icon>
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="labor" class="mainTollbar-button">
      <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle value="study" class="mainTollbar-button">
      <mat-icon>pageview</mat-icon>
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
  My App
</mat-toolbar>
<div class="example-selected-value">Selected value: {{modeAppWorking.value}}</div>
```

The style:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
:host {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.mainToolbar{
  @include mat-elevation(8);  
  padding: 7px;
  .mainTollbar-button{
    color: red;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;    
    mat-icon{
      font-size: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
    }    
  }
}
.example-selected-value {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular material adds a `div` with a class `mat-button-toggle-label-content` that contains padding around the `mat-icon` element. To overcome this padding, use `position: relative` and `left` to move the icon to the center.

```css
mat-icon{
    position: relative;
    left: -8px;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```